# Почему print не выполняется при каждом значении True в if

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Только начинаю изучать Python, столкнулся с такой вот проблемой

```
for i in range(30):
    if i in [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]:
        print('ы', end='')
```

По задумке, в этом отрывке кода, программа должна выводить "ы" через каждые 5 значений, но в процессе исполнения ничего не происходит. Программа выводит сразу 5 букв перед самым её завершением.
Как сделать так, чтобы буквы выводились именно во время исполнения программы?

Comment: Что значит "перед самым ее завершением" и "во время исполнения" и чем это должно отличаться от того, что вы наблюдаете сейчас?

Comment: Такой цикл выполняется за несколько микросекунд. Как вы собираетесь видеть отличия в поведении, если за несколько микросекунд даже экран вашего монитора обновиться не успеет?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: это просто пример, допустим, я хочу отслеживать процесс исполнения программы, обрабатывающей в 1000 раз больше данных в долях, т. е. программа будет выводить какой-либо знак каждую десятую часть обработанных данных. соответственно, на экране будет появляться символ, допустим, каждые две секунды. таким образом, я должен примерно понимать, сколько нужно ждать до конца работы программы. В данном случае отличия в поведении легко различимы через дебагер

Comment: Это очень неудачный пример, потому что он совершенно не демонстрирует проблему. Используйте аргумент flush=True в принте, чтобы принудительно вывести всё во время принта

Comment: про flush и буферы я пока ничего не знаю, поэтому, можете написать конкретный пример с их использованием?

Comment: print(..., flush=True)

Comment: спасибо, flush действительно помог )

Answer (score 2):

Всё у вас работает. Чтобы продемонстрировать, введём в вашу программу нехитрую запись, а именно будем писать каждую i.

input:

```
for i in range(30):
    print(i)
    if i in [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]:
        print('ы', end='')
```

output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
ы6
7
8
9
10
ы11
12
13
14
15
ы16
17
18
19
20
ы21
22
23
24
25
ы26
27
28
29
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь 2 проблемы:

1. Вывод индивидуальных символов идет *не прямо в консоль,* а до [буфера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Только когда встретится символ перехода на новую строку (`'\n`'), содержание буфера выводится на консоль и буфер обнуляться.

   Таким образом возможно сказать, что на консоль выводится строка после строки.
2. Компьютер работает *с удивительной скоростью,* так что *кажется, что всё выводится сразу.*

---

Как вашу программу исправить, чтобы она работала по вашем?

1. Вместо команды

   ```
   print('ы', end='')       # символы в одну строку, они входят сначала в буфер
   ```

   используйте

   ```
   print('ы')               # каждый символ в своей строке, выводится сразу
   ```
2. Замедлите ход программы функцией `sleep()` *(«спать»)* из модуля `time` встроенной библиотеки:

   ```
   sleep(0.25)              # ожидать четверть секунды
   ```

Также ваш адаптированный код может выглядеть так:

```
from time import sleep


for i in range(30):
    sleep(0.25)
    if i in [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]:
        print('ы')
```

Comment: > "выводится строка после строки." По логике пункта 1, скорее "выводится строка перед строкой"? Предыдущая строка ушла на консоль, в буфере набирается текущая строка.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, вы прав, выбор фразы "выводится строка после строки" не очень счастливым. Я хотел им сказать, что вывод на экран есть построчный, а не посимвольный.